# Could I use jar source code instead of a .jar file?

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to use the .jar source code instead of the .jar file to run an app as I wanted to customize what the jar did in my application.

Comment: If you have the source of your jar file (the .java files) then you can put them and the folders of the package in your java\ folder

Comment: use `jd gui` open that jar and go to option `save as source` you can use this source package in your application.

Comment: I tried to attach sources to the files directly before but each time I did the grade sync it reset to the way the original jar was. If I put it in the Java/ folder it won't do this?

Comment: If you put the source in the java/ folder then you can even delete the original jar, it will still work. You just need the Decompiled .java files out of the jar (or the original source, e.g. from gitHub).

Comment: Would it be the same if it was in the src folder? That's the folder with the rest of my code for the app. The reason I'm asking is that when I tried moving my files to the Java folder I lost the Java package which is how each Java file performs its imports. By the way I'm working with ical4j and I'm trying to get the getCategories() method. And I'm working with the .Java files from github.

Comment: Or is it src/Java instead?